# Creating a phonebook using linked list and file operations

Tags: c, data-structures

I was creating a phonebook in C using single linked list. The issue that I am experiencing in GCC is that at certain lines, GCC is throwing assignment to expression with array type errors. And at certain lines, it is giving me warning like format %s expects an argument of type char*.

I have tried without the sorting function by putting it in comments and executing. The program executes and asks for the number, first name and last name. But then only the first name and last name is shown properly. The phone number displays some odd value which looks like the memory address.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    char firstname[20];
    char lastname[20];
    int number[15];
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *start=NULL;

struct node *getnode()
{
    return((struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node)));
} 


void display(struct node *start)
{
    struct node *temp;
    temp=start;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n",temp->firstname);
        printf("%s\n",temp->lastname);
        printf("%d\n",temp->number);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}
/*void sort()
{
    struct node *temp,*pretemp;
    char *p;
    temp=start;
    pretemp=start->next;
    while(pretemp!=NULL)
    {
    if(strcmp(temp->lastname,pretemp->lastname)>0)
    {
        if(temp->lastname==pretemp->lastname)
        {
            if(strcmp(temp->firstname,pretemp->firstname)>0)
            {
                p=temp->firstname;
                temp->firstname=pretemp->firstname;
                pretemp->firstname=p;   
            }
        }
        else
        {
                p=temp->lastname;
                temp->lastname=pretemp->firstname;
                pretemp->firstname=p;
        }
    }
    }
}
*/
void insert()
{
    struct node *temp,*nn;
    nn=getnode();
    temp=start;
    while(temp->next!=NULL)
    {
        temp=temp->next;
        
    }
    printf("Enter First name:\n");
    scanf("%s",&nn->firstname);
    printf("Enter Last name:\n");
    scanf("%s",&nn->lastname);
    printf("Enter number:\n");
    scanf("%d",&nn->number);
    temp->next=nn;
    nn->next=NULL;
    display(start);
}

struct node *create()
{
    struct node *temp,*nn;
    if(start!=NULL)
        insert();
    else
    {
    nn=getnode();
    start=nn;
    temp=start;
    printf("Enter First name:\n");
    scanf("%s",&nn->firstname);
    printf("Enter Last name:\n");
    scanf("%s",&nn->lastname);
    printf("Enter number:\n");
    scanf("%d",&nn->number);
    nn->next=NULL;
    display(start);
    }
}
void search()
{
    struct node *temp;
    char *f,*l;
    temp=start;
    printf("Enter name to be searched:\n");
    scanf("%s",&f);
    scanf("%s",&l);
    while((temp->firstname==f)&&(temp->lastname==l))
    {
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    printf("%s\n",temp->firstname);
    printf("%s\n",temp->lastname);
    printf("%d\n",temp->number);
}

void del()
{
    struct node *pretemp,*temp;
    char *f,*l;
    temp=start;
    pretemp=start->next;
    printf("Enter name :");
    scanf("%s",&f);
    scanf("%s",&l);
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        if((pretemp->firstname==f)&&(pretemp->lastname==l))
        {
            printf("%s ",temp->firstname);
            printf("%s ",temp->lastname);
            printf("%s ",temp->number);
            temp->next=pretemp->next;
            free(pretemp);
            break;
        }
        else 
        {
            temp=temp->next;
            pretemp=pretemp->next;
        }
        
        
    }
}

int main()
{
    int op,ch;
    do{
        printf("-------Welcome--------\n ");
        printf("1.Create\n2.Insert\n3.Display\n4.Delete\n5.Search\n6.Sort\n");
        printf("Enter your choice:");
        scanf("%d",&ch);
        switch(ch)
        {
            case 1: create();
            break;
            case 2: insert();
            break;
            case 3: display(start);
            break;
            case 4: del();
            break;
            case 5:search();
            break;
            /*case 6:sort();
            break;*/
        }
        printf("Do you want to quit ? 1 for no / 0 for yes:");
        scanf("%d",&op);
    }while(op!=0);
return 0;
}
```

```
roschlynn@Roschlynn-Asus:/mnt/c/Users/ROSCHLYNN D'SOUZA/Desktop/Test$ ./a.out
-------Welcome--------
 1.Create
2.Insert
3.Display
4.Delete
5.Search
6.Sort
Enter your choice:1
Enter First name:
Ivan
Enter Last name:
Dsouza
Enter number:
123456789
Ivan
Dsouza
-499915096
Do you want to quit ? 1 for no / 0 for yes:0
roschlynn@Roschlynn-Asus:/mnt/c/Users/ROSCHLYNN D'SOUZA/Desktop/Test$
```

I expect the output to be the phone number that i entered but it appears that it is taking the memory address of the number.

Comment: `int number[15];` Do you mean "this is a 15 digit number"? Numbers don't work this way in C. Or do you mean "this guy has 15 phone numbers"? That could be too much.

Comment: No. We have 9 digit numbers here in India. But, even when i enter a 9 digit number it appears to pull the memory address i think

Comment: Changing the following line in the `display` function: `printf("%d\n",temp->number);` to `printf("%d\n",temp->number[0]);` resolves the issue(only hides the underlying problem). But there a multiple issues in your implementation.

Comment: What does `[15]` *mean*?

Answer (score 0):

If you just change `int number[15];` to `long number;` it works as expected.

Comment: Actually I would use `unsigned long`, Since this type will handle up to 10 digits and since you know a phone number will never be negative and <= 9 digits it is perfect

Comment: Actually, `unsigned long` is only guaranteed to contain [0, 2^32), and thus isn't enough to store all 9 digit numbers (and is 32-bits on many platforms). You'll need an `unsigned long long` or use `uint64_t` from `stdint.h` and worry less about portability. (Remember, C predates pervasive 32-bit machines)

Comment: Am I missing something or is `4,294,967,296‬` > 999,999,999

Comment: True, I was thinking 10-digit numbers sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `uint64_t` to store phone numbers refer following updated code,

```
#include<stdint.h>
 struct node
{
    char firstname[20];
    char lastname[20];
    uint64_t number;
    struct node *next;
};
```

Change scanf() and printf(),

```
scanf("%llu",&nn->number);
printf("%llu",temp->number);
```